# Adding Month-to-date and Year-to-date in a query using SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database, date, subquery, union

so I'm trying to make a query that includes a daily sum of the amount from the first instance the database starts collecting data to the last available instance of that date (database collects data every hour). And while I have done this, now I have to make it show a month to date and a year to date sum amount. I have tried various ways to come up with this but have had no luck. Below is the code that I believe is the closest I have gotten to achieve this. Can someone help me make my code work or suggest another way around this?

```
Select * from
(
SELECT      Devices.DeviceDesc,
SUM(DeviceSummaryData.Amount) AS MTD, 
Devices.Area,
MIN(DeviceSummaryData.StartDate) AS FirstOfStartDate, 
MAX(DeviceSummaryData.EndDate) AS LastOfStartDate
FROM Devices INNER JOIN DeviceSummaryData ON Devices.DeviceID = DeviceSummaryData.DeviceID
WHERE (DeviceSummaryData.StartDate = MONTH(getdate())) AND (DeviceSummaryData.EndDate <= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) 
                         AS date))
GROUP BY Devices.DeviceDesc, Devices.Area, DATEPART(day, DeviceSummaryData.StartDate)
--
) q2

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  Devices.DeviceDesc,
        Sum(Amount) as Daily,
        Devices.Area,
        MIN(StartDate) as FirstDate,
        MAX(DeviceSummaryData.EndDate) AS LastOfStartDate

FROM Devices INNER JOIN DeviceSummaryData ON Devices.DeviceID = DeviceSummaryData.DeviceID

WHERE (DeviceSummaryData.StartDate >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) AS date)) AND (DeviceSummaryData.EndDate <= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, getdate()) AS date))

GROUP BY Devices.Area,
         Devices.DeviceDesc,
         DATEPART(day, DeviceSummaryData.StartDate)

ORDER BY Devices.DeviceDesc
) q2
```

Another type of attempt I have tried would be this:

```
SELECT  Devices.DeviceDesc,
        Sum(case 
            when DeviceSummaryData.StartDate >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, getdate()) AS date) 
            THEN Amount
            else 0 
            end) as Daily,
        Sum(case 
            when Month(StartDate) = MONTH(getdate()) 
            THEN Amount 
            else 0 
            end) as MTD,
        Devices.Area,
        MIN(StartDate) as FirstDate,
        MAX(DeviceSummaryData.EndDate) AS LastOfStartDate

FROM Devices INNER JOIN DeviceSummaryData ON Devices.DeviceID = DeviceSummaryData.DeviceID

WHERE (DeviceSummaryData.StartDate >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) AS date)) AND (DeviceSummaryData.EndDate <= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, getdate()) AS date))

GROUP BY Devices.Area,
         Devices.DeviceDesc,
         DATEPART(day, DeviceSummaryData.StartDate)

ORDER BY Devices.DeviceDesc
```

I'm not the best with Case When's, but I saw somewhere that this is a possible way to do this. I'm not too concerned with the speed or efficiency, I just need it to generate the query to be able to get the data. Any help and Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second attempt is on the right track but a bit confused. In the `CASE` statements you are trying to compare months etc, but your `WHERE` clause restricts the data you're looking at to a single day. Also, your `GROUP BY` should not include the day anymore. If you say in English what you want, it's "For each device area and type, I want to see a total, a MTD total and a YTD total". It's that "For each" bit that should define what appears in your `GROUP BY`.

Just remove the `WHERE` clause entirely and get rid of `DATEPART(day, DeviceSummaryData.StartDate)` from your `GROUP BY` and you should get the results you want. (Well, a daily and monthly total, anyway. Yearly is achieved much the same way).

Also note that `DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE())` is identical to just `GETDATE()`.

Comment: This worked! Adding to that, I kept in the Where statement, but only to restrict it to the current year.